# CSS causing an UL to be indented too much in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I have a navigation bar at the top of a page. In FF and Chrome the navigation bar displays fine. However in IE8 (with or without compatibility) the UL seems to indent from the left hand side, not each li just the whole li; despite declaring

```
text-align:center; width:600px; margin:auto; padding-left:0;
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
margin-left:0px;
```

In Firefox the UL is padded left by default, in IE it has a left margin.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

ul{
border:1px solid red;
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
padding:0px;
}

li{
border:1px solid green;
margin:0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li>this</li>
<li>that</li>
<li>these</li>
<li>those</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15):

I just used ul { list-style-position:outside; } to fix the indent in IE.

Comment: thumbs up. most of the answers i get are margin:0, padding 0. This is also needed for IE so that it works like other browsers.

Comment: I always forget about this silly bit and then revisit the issue some months in the future - nice post.

Answer (score 4):

I think it should be:

```
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0 } 
li { padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list-style-position:outside;` specifically for IE6/IE7 worked for me. However, note that this may only be necessary if you're using `list-style-position:inside;` for other browsers and simply hiding the default list margin/padding by setting them to 0. Working with IE requires some finesse, and a lot of browser-specific CSS.