# Is it redundant to set same style and padding for UL and LI?

Tags: css

Is it necessary to do the following:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or is just having these styles on `ul` sufficient?

Is there a browser compatibility reason for having it on both?

Comment: Just having it on the `ul` seems to be sufficient. [See](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/PnS9f/)

Comment: See the default style sheets (which can be "fixed" across browsers by a CSS reset). And yes, there *is* a difference: which will be obvious for non-0 values (and borders/outlines for quick visualization).

Comment: @JoshC Yeah, was wondering why a lot of tutorials have both (seen it like this on css-tricks.com too).

Comment: @user2864740 Ahh... so if using a proper reset, this won't be needed.

Comment: @Hopstream Well, you'll start at a "uniform base" - all modern browsers should otherwise render it the same, for the values that are set. I believe the issue is that there have historically been issues with on *which* element the default style margin was set, which is why tutorials (without a reset) apply it to both.

Comment: @Hopstream I have always played it safe and applied that styling to both.. (i.e. `ul, li { style.. }`)

Comment: @Hopstream See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1184793/2864740 (that was for IE6/7 at least, not sure how IE8+ works)

Comment: @Hopstream However, http://www.iecss.com/ indicates that `li` *never* had a padding/margin in IE6/7, so it seems like only [re]setting the `ul` margin/padding is required for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not unnecessary.

```
ul { /* this is an unordered list */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li { /* this is an unordered list item */
    list-style-type: none; /* perhaps only this is redundant. */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

`UL` are basicaly displayed has block elements while `LI` are displayed has list-items.

You might have to style them separately, and redundance is because the 'list-style' is inherited.